# How do you define user in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to run some test events and I tried using the one discord.js posted on their website:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
        console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    },
};
```

I tried googling how to define a user but it only led to specific answers for that specific scenerio.

Here is my code for the event handler:

```
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const fs = require('fs');
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
/Users/me/RPG Bot/events/ready.js:5
        console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.id}`);
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/Users/dkaplan/RPG Bot/events/ready.js:5:45)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/dkaplan/RPG Bot/bot.js:40:46)
```

Thank you to anyone that can help.

Comment: Can we see the file where you call the command?

Answer (score -1):

It doesnt look like you are ever declaring `client`.

As per the discord.js documentation:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

Comment: I tried adding: `const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {user, tag} = new Discord.Client();` to my code but I got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`

Comment: `client` is an argument from `execute()`